# HTTP compression - can I configure a client to compress the data sent to a server?

Tags: .net, http, iis, soap, compression

I'm using IIS 7 as web server for my application. If I enable dynamic content compression in the server, will this also enable clients to send compressed data to the server, if they can?

I mean, my application uses SOAP webservices, and clients usually send large chunks of data to the server. The clients are written in C#/.NET. Is there any kind of configuration I can do in a web reference / serice reference in order to tell them to compress the content before they send it to IIS? And do I have to do any kind of configuration in IIS in order for this to work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HTTP compression works by the client specifying an `Accept-Encoding` header with the compression types it accepts:

> Accept-Encoding: compress, gzip

The server then sees this and will chose one of the encoding types based on the [accept encoding rules defined here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html).  The response will be in one of the accepted values or the identity encoding.

---

**Requests:**

In general a request can't come in compressed first because the communication starts with a request.  An HTTP client could send an options request though and use that if you have control of the client and server source code you could do this.

> The OPTIONS method represents a request for information about the communication options available on the request/response chain identified by the Request-URI. This method allows the client to determine the options and/or requirements associated with a resource, or the capabilities of a server, without implying a resource action or initiating a resource retrieval.

An example of this is an apache module for SVN, and also an svn client.  They can be configured to do HTTP compression on the request data.

[See RFC 2616: Section 9](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)

Comment: It turned out that I was wrong, in the sense that data transfer isn't my application's bottleneck. So, I decided not to worry much about sending compressed requests. But thanks for the useful answer.